# How to find if file exist with msbuild command(or before)

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

I need to find if certain file exist prior to the run of a power-shell script

The file (if exist) will be in a specific folder.

Can i check for it's existence through the `proj` file or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Note the second MyCheck looks at the (conditional) value of (the first) MyCheck

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <MyCheck Condition="Exists($(MyFileOrFolderName))">true</MyCheck>
        <MyCheck Condition="'$(MyCheck)'==''">false</MyCheck>
    </PropertyGroup>  
    <Message Text="My-File-Or-Folder-Name already exists? :  $(MyCheck)" />
```

OR

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <MyCheck>false</MyCheck>
        <MyCheck Condition="Exists($(MyFileOrFolderName))">true</MyCheck>
    </PropertyGroup>  
    <Message Text="MyFileOrFolderNameexists? :  $(MyCheck)" />
```

Comment: Slightly shorter: set MyCheck to False unconditionally but move the line up so it comes before the conditional assignment. Or even shorter: just assign the result of Exists to the property directly and you only need one line

Comment: I'll go with the first recommendation (made an edit to my post), but the second would be empty string vs true.

Comment: You're right, my mistake: `Exists` only works in a condition. You could use `<MyCheck >$([System.IO.File]::Exists('$(MyFile)'))</MyCheck >` for example, but that's only for files and not for folders and the syntax is a bit harder to remember

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute PS script, depending on the existance of a file, you can create a `Target` element in your *.*proj file with condition depending on the file existance:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="14.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ScriptLocation>.\Do-Something.ps1</ScriptLocation>
    <PowerShellExe Condition=" '$(PowerShellExe)'=='' ">%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
    </PowerShellExe>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="RunPSScript" Condition="Exists($(ScriptLocation))">
    <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;$(ScriptLocation)&quot;"/>  
  </Target>
</Project>
```

See more details [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/running-windows-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-project-files) about executing PS scripts from msbuild projects. You can use AfterTargets, BeforeTargers, or [any other methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee216359.aspx)  to control order of the execution this target.